# After using http_substitutions_filter module, nginx ignores `Range` http header

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, nginx-module

I recently try to use `http_substitution_filter_module` to filter and replace some content in my nginx server.
After I added the `subs_filter` rule, I can no longer use `Range` header to retrieve the part of file but the full content.

Example:
`flag.txt` in `/var/www/html` with content:

```
The flag is FLAG{IAMFLAGYEEAH}.
```

I can use `curl -r 13-16 <server-address>/flag.txt` to get only part of file. Output:

```
LAG{
```

But if I enabled `sub_filter` rule, `Range` header no longer works.
By using same command, I get the following result:

```
The flag is FLAG{NOFLAGFORYOU}.
```

Although filter works perfectly, the full content is returned.

Here is my `nginx/sites-enabled/default` config (other settings is same as the default one):

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    subs_filter_types text/plain;
    subs_filter "FLAG{\w*}" "FLAG{NOFLAGFORYOU}" ir;
}
```

and my nginx version is `1.14.0`.
The module was installed by command `apt install libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter`.

How should I keep `Range` header working and also filter the content at the same time?